# Retrain Multiclassification ITransformer

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I created a ITransformer model based on the SdcaMaximumEntropy trainer from the MulticlassClassification :

```
var trainingPipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy())
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
ITransformer trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(splitTrainSet);
```

Now I want to retrain it with the Fit method by applying the original model parameters :

```
var originalModelParameters = ((MulticlassPredictionTransformer<object>)model).Model as MaximumEntropyModelParameters;
            model = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy().Fit(newData, originalModelParameters);
```

But I get an error on the Fit method :

> No overload for method 'Fit' takes 2 arguments

So I'm aware that the Fit method from the SdcaMaximumEntropy trainer doesn't have the required Fit method with 2 arguments, but I am wondering how can I retrain my multiclassification model without it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `SdcaMaximumEntrpy` trainer isn't in [the list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net) of trainers that can be retrained. Perhaps you can try `LbfgsMaximumEntropyMulticlassTrainer` instead?

Hopefully, in the future, more trainers will be able to be retrained.